# how to let image to have a fixed rotation around the upper left corner

Tags: itext, itext7

image.setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(-300));
This method doesn't seem to rotate around a fixed point and beyond the PDF size, which is not what I want?

Comment: First of all, a rotation has a fixed point. Otherwise it's no rotation. Furthermore, please indicate how you add your image to the PDF. Because depending on whether you add at a fixed position or not, there is a difference how rotation is handled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.